# Import Error on Django app

Tags: django, importerror

I'm getting the following error message:

```
ImportError at /youtube_submit
No module named util.process
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://myapp.com:8000/youtube_submit?videoid=vSlF8EFo8QA
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named util.process
Exception Location: /Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/trainee/views/youtube_submit.py in <module>, line 6
Python Executable:  /Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.27-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/filipeximenes/Projects/trainee/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

This is my requirements file:

```
Django==1.4.1
South==0.7.6
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==2.7.3.12
celery==3.0.9
distribute==0.6.27
dj-database-url==0.2.1
django-celery==3.0.9
facebook-sdk==0.3.2
gdata==2.0.17
gunicorn==0.14.6
kombu==2.4.5
psycopg2==2.4.5
python-dateutil==1.5
python-openid==2.2.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I'm running the app locally, and I do have `__init__.py` files in all my modules.
And the app is installed:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'main',
    'trainee',
    'company',
    'videos',
    'south',
)
```

I have other apps working perfectly, the only one that is giving me pain is the `videos`one.

Any ideas on whats the problem?

EDIT:

youtube submit imports:
`from videos.util.process import verify_video`
process.py imports:
`from videos.util.youtube import YoutubeUtil`
youtube.py imports:
`import gdata.youtube.service`
`import urlparse`
`from videos.util.verifier import Verifier`
verifier.py doesn't import anything

EDIT:

I created another app and copied all files to it.
I magically started working.

Comment: Your traceback clearly says `No module named util.process`

Comment: Have you added videos app to urls.py?

Comment: This is the import that is giving the error: `from videos.util.process import verify_video`
the videos module is more an library, so I don't have any urls in it.

Comment: so the file struct looks like this: myprojec/videos/util/process.py
and in the process file i have: def verify_video(args)

Comment: @Filipe do you have `myprojec/videos/util/__init__.py` file? Maybe circular imports?

Comment: I do have the init.py. Circular imports may be the problem, but I've looked at this already and couldn't find any problems.

Comment: have you tried to import the utils.process just before it is being used (rather than at the top of the file?) This way you can avoid circular dependencies

Comment: I edited the question, can you have a look?

Comment: @karthikr I just tried this, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another app and copied all files to it. Somehow it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In /youtube_submit view of videos application you have imported something like this,

```
from util.process import *
```

And since ther's no such module or the folder **process** has no __init__.py file, you get this error

Comment: This is the import that is giving the error:
`from videos.util.process import verify_video` and as I said, I do have the `__init__.py` files.